# Display the Arabic String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextview

How to display the following dynamic font to UITextView.

**\U0648\U0632\U0646 \U0627\U0644\U0645\U0646\U062a\U062c**

Comment: "dynamic font"?  That's a UTF-16 string.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415125/ios-uitextview-with-special-characters

Comment: how to display this type of strings to UITextView

Answer (score 1):

refer cStringUsingEncoding from [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class

Answer (score 1):

`\U` escape expects 8 digits. `\u` expects 4.

Use `\u` instead.

```
NSString *string = @"\u0648\u0632\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u062a\u062c";
NSLog(@"%@", string);

//Produces:
//2012-11-27 12:35:02.199 AppName[4370:707] وزن المنتج
```

Comment: this give error \u using following hex digits

Comment: hi its work for static text but dynamic data is update how to handle please help me.

Comment: I'll need to see what your input looks like. How do you get this "dynamic text"? Add the info to your question.